# Can't get multiple results with my query when adding a left join

Tags: mysql, join

My query without a left join gathers 2 results as it should, when I add the left join I acquire only 1.

Firstly here is my query:

```
SELECT cb_keys.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cb_AllowedIPs.IP4) AS IP4, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cb_ModulesInKey.ActionID) AS Actions
FROM cb_keys
LEFT JOIN cb_allowedips ON cb_Keys.KeyID = cb_allowedips.KeyID
LEFT JOIN cb_modulesinkey ON cb_keys.KeyID = cb_modulesinkey.KeyID
WHERE cb_Keys.UserID = 2
GROUP BY cb_Keys.UserID
```

Now I will reflect on some of my tables:
**cb_keys**

```
KeyID |  UserID | Key
--------------------------
1     |    2    | 20fjewof
2     |    2    | eiwfjow2
```

**cb_allowedips**

```
ipID |  KeyID | Address
--------------------------
1    |    1   | 127.0.0.1
2    |    2   | 127.0.0.1
```

**cb_modulesinkey**

```
modkeyID |  KeyID | ActionID
--------------------------
1        |    1   | 1
2        |    2   | 4
```

So I am working with 2 Key rows which both have an identifier of 2 (which satisfies the WHERE condition), each of the keys have 1 address and finally each of the keys have 1 action. I have several of the addresses and actions in my database which is why I GROUP_CONCAT to make things easier in PHP.

If I was to remove the joins, and had just my SELECT, FROM and WHERE I will return 2 rows, my intention is to return 2 rows but to add on the little extras that I am trying to do. Now as it stands with my joins added I only return 1 row rather than 2 even though they both satisfy.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return both rows, the aggregate by the row id, not the user id:

```
GROUP BY cb_Keys.KeyID
```